# Django ValueError Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: django, pandas, numpy

i am getting this error. one df dataframe is read from json API and second df2 is read from csv i want to compare one column of csv to API and then matched value to save into new csv. can anyone help me

```
df2=pd.read_csv(file_path)
    r = requests.get('https://data.ct.gov/resource/6tja-6vdt.json')
    df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
    df['verified'] = np.where(df['salespersoncredential'] == df2['salespersoncredential'],'True', 'False')
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably just make `df['verified'] = np.where(df['salespersoncredential'] == df2['salespersoncredential'],'True', 'False')`

this

```
df['verified'] = df['salespersoncredential'] == df2['salespersoncredential']
```

assuming the dtypes and are correct.

If the indexes are different on the two dataframes, you might need to `.reset_index()`.

Comment: These are same datatypes

Comment: not solved with this can you give another solution?

Comment: Can you print both series? If the indexes are different, you need to figure out why.

Comment: Yes I can print dataframes